# Subtract months from a given date in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to subtract months from a given date.

```
businessDate='2019-12-31'
diff=1
busDate=$(date --date="$businessDate -$diff month" +%Y-%m-%d)
echo "Date: $busDate"
```

This code returns 2019-12-01 instead of 2019-11-30. Can someone please suggest a solution to get the correct date?

Comment: Hm, you have to define it better.  Let's assume the input is `2019-03-31` or `2019-03-30` or `2019-03-29` or `2019-03-28` for each of those 4 inputs the output will be the same `2019-02-28`? And for the year `2020` the output will be `2020-02-29` for any `2020-03-{29,31}`? So basically you want to substract one month, then if the number of days is greater then the number of days in the resulting month, then truncate the number of days to the last day in the month, right?

Comment: For 3 inputs - `2019-03-31` or `2019-03-30` or `2019-03-29` , I am getting different results - `2019-03-03` or `2019-03-02` or `2019-03-01` respectively. Is this an issue with the date function? I am not very familiar with bash.

Comment: I ask, what do you want to have, what is your expected, ideal output. No it's not an issue. Calendar time is really, really complicated topic. It depends on how you interpret a "month".

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. Yes, for the 3 inputs of march - I would want the date `2019-02-28` as my result. As you stated, I want to subtract 1 month from the given date and if the days are greater than resulting month then just return the last date of previous month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicate in 'info date', calculation of dates with relative month (1 month ago, etc.) is problematic, and sometime result in unexpected results:

From: 29.7 Relative items in date strings:

> The fuzz in units can cause problems with relative items.  For
>   example, ‘2003-07-31 -1 month’ might evaluate to 2003-07-01, because
>   2003-06-31 is an invalid date

Some solutions:

1. Treat '1 month ago' as a request to move  days backward, where N is max(DD, days in previous month).
2. Check if the result date has the same month as the original date, and move the date one day backward from the first day of the month. This is needed to handle March/Feb transition.
3. Alternative approach is to perform the date movement on the first day of the month (which will always work), and then to cap the day part of the date, but the last date in the result month.

The benefit of the third approach is that it words for for  month movement.

Implementation of option #3 is bash is a little bit cumbersome, probably better to write python/perl code.

```
IDATE=2019-12-31
N_MONTH=-1
DD_PART=$(date +'%d' -d "$IDATE")
YYYYMM=$(date +'%Y-%m' -d "$(date +'%Y-%m-01' -d "$IDATE") $N_MONTH month")
LAST_DAY_IN_YYYYMM=$(date +'%d' -d "$YYYYMM-01 +1month -1day")
if [[ "$LAST_DAY_IN_YYYYMM" -lt "$DD_PART" ]] ; then
    DD_PART=$LAST_DAY_IN_YYYYMM
fi
echo "$YYYYMM-$DD_PART"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @TannikaAggarwal noticed revised solution, which will work for generic N month movement - backward or forward.

Comment: @AndreySScherbakov please check the updated code, it was extended to handle +N and -N month, and correctly handles MArch/Feb transition. The output I get for IDATE=2019-03-31 is 2019-02-28.

Comment: To get this to work on days 01-09 it needs this: <br>  `TMP=\`echo $DD_PART | sed -e 's/^0//'\`  
if [[ "$LAST_DAY_IN_YYYYMM" -lt "$TMP" ]] ; then`

Answer (score 0):

First, this is actually the correct date! '2019-12-31' minus one months would be '2019-11-31' but as we have only 30 day in November, it maps to December, the 1st.

Still, if you want to get to the previous month for sure (I think it's namely what you want!), I may propose to add as many extra days as one needs for that. Please try this code:

```
businessDate='2019-12-3'
diff=1

thisMonth=$(date --date=$businessDate +%m)
extra=0 #extra days to reach the previous month for sure
while [ $(date --date="$businessDate -$diff month -$extra days" +%m) == $thisMonth ]
do
    extra=`expr $extra + 1`
done


busDate=$(date --date="$businessDate -$diff month -$extra days" +%Y-%m-%d)
echo "Date: $busDate"
```